# URL Rewriting in ASP.Net MVC 2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have written below code to achieve URL Rewriting.

**In Global.asax**

```
          routes.MapRoute(
          "StudentDetail", // Route name
          "StudentDetail", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "UDashboard", action = "UAboutMeStudentDetails", 
                SortField =  UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

In View

```
 <a href="/StudentDetail?SortField='Major'" >Students</a>
```

When i click link, it goes to action of controller which is perfect.

But my URL is

```
 https://localhost/StudentDetail?SortField='Major'
```

and i don't want that.

I just want my URL as

```
 https://localhost/StudentDetail
```

What change should I do to achieve above URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value of SortField to always be Major, but not to show it in the Url, then you need to just do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "StudentDetail", // Route name
   "StudentDetail", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "UDashboard", action = "UAboutMeStudentDetails", 
         SortField = "Major" }
);
```

But, if Major is showing up in your Url, it means when you are generating your links you are passing that to the helper somehow.  You need to make sure you remove that from the helper.  If you still want to accept a field, but default to Major, then you would do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "StudentDetail", // Route name
   "StudentDetail/{SortField}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "UDashboard", action = "UAboutMeStudentDetails", 
         SortField = "Major" }
);
```

Comment: I have tried above code and it worked fine.
Now i have one question, The above code i have written for single page but in my application i have 80 different pages, and i have to write 80 different routes. So the question is is this a good way to write 80 routres in Global.asax or i can do this by doing some other functionality...?

Don't you think performance will degrade, if we will write 80 routes in Global.asax file..?

Comment: @PrashantBhojani - Well, if you have 80 different unique routes, you don't have much choice.  This is why MVC uses a convention by default, so you don't need to write such routes, but you chose to use specific routes instead.. Having said that, a simple match of 80 routes will have some performance overhead, but probably not noticeable by you or your users.

Comment: I have written above code but still my url is https://localhost/StudentDetail?SortField=Major , So how can i change it to https://localhost/StudentDetail/Major ...?

Comment: @PrashantBhojani - Show your complete set of routes.  Chances are another more specific route is taking over ahead of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways involving TempData or Session to store in some way the parameter and call the `GET` with a clean link:

```
<a href="/StudentDetail" >Students</a>
```

But you can use a different approach that can be more consistent, changing the `GET` action to `POST` and sending the `SortField` inside a hidden field, something like that to start, because I don't tested it:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UAboutMeStudentDetails", "UDashboard", new { SortField = "Major" }, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.Hidden("SortField", "Major")
    <button type="submit">Students</button>
}
```